# Usual frontier symbology of a set

Tags: general-topology

Generally when I have studied mathematical analysis at my university, I denoted with $\partial X$ the frontier of a set $X\subseteq \mathbb R^n$.

I have seen other symbologies like:

**1.** $FX$ (see the image below),

[image]

and

**2.** $\mathcal F X$ (see the image below),

[image]

But, does exist other symbols?

> What is the more common symbol in the world to use?

Comment: What is your definition of frontier of a set?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma A point is defined as a frontier point when it belongs to the edge of the whole: note that a frontier point of a set may not belong to the set. Or, border point for a whole is a $P$ point such that in each of its circles there are both points of the whole and points of its complementary. The border of a set is the set of its border points, it can be obtained as the difference between the closure of the set and its inside.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Here in a page of Italian Wikipedia there is your notation :-o: https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frontiera_(topologia).

Comment: I normally use $\operatorname{bdry}A$ or occasionally $\operatorname{bdry}(A)$. I dislike $\partial A$, though it is rather common. As Henno says, $\operatorname{Fr}A$ and $\operatorname{Bd}A$ are also quite standard (also with parentheses around $A$). I have not seen the notations in your question.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you very much for your comment. But before there are the notations, $\partial X$, $FX$ and $\mathcal FX$ or $\mathcal F(X)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've seen (besides the (I think) most common  $\partial X$) mostly $\operatorname{Fr}(X)$, $\operatorname{Bd}(X)$; some texts even distinguish these ("frontier" as set minus its interior, boundary as closure of a set minus its interior, e.g. so then "frontier" points of $X$ are in $X$ by definition, the closure definition is more common).

Comment: I never have seen $\operatorname{Fr}(X)$ and $\operatorname{Bd}(X)$ in the my life. But is it relative to $\complement X$? Just a simple curiosity, do you can some simplest examples? Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: @Sebastiano See books by Engelking, Willard etc. which use $\operatorname{Fr}(X)$. The notion of boundary  isn't used that much, really. Dimension theory mostly. What do you mean by "relative to $\mathsf{C} X$"? I've never seen $FX$ or $\mathscr{F}X$ used. "Do you can some simple examples"? Not English, don't know what you mean.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma that $CX$ is the complement of $X$ in the ambient space; you might write it as $X^c$ or ${\mathbb R}\setminus X$

Comment: Look the $FX$, $\mathcal FX$ in the images of my edit. Excuse me but it is in Italian language.

Comment: @Sebastiano whence the picture? You own university? That’s not a source, probably a personal notation of some teacher.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma No, I'm a teacher of an high school. Yes, I think that you have right. Business Administration - Administration and Control of a student studying in Sicily.